# Is there a pastebin for Markdown?

Tags: web-apps, markdown, sharing, pastebin

I want to share Markdown files with others, very much like [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) does for JavaScript files.

Answer (score 12):

**[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/)** supports MarkDown.

On the homepage enter your code, and select "Markdown" from the language list. You can publish your gist publicly (shows up in results of search engines) secretly (doesn't show up in search results, but the gist is still accessible for everyone who has the link).

Here's a basic example: [gist.github.com/basilevs/de72b93d72a80d078f29](https://gist.github.com/basilevs/de72b93d72a80d078f29).

For more information about creating gists in general, refer to [Creating gists - User Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-gists/)

Comment: I didn't know GitHub Gist supports MarkDown, but it appears to not have a side-by-side editor, as NoteHub does.

Comment: Github gist requires  signup tho...

Answer (score 6):

[Rentry](https://rentry.co/) is fast and simple and supports MarkDown.

Answer (score 1):

**[Write.as](https://write.as/)** is a writing platform (dare I say they compete with Medium?) which uses Markdown. You can [write anonymous posts](https://write.as/new), here's an [example](https://write.as/m9fypl3jne6dr.md) (posted on 4 Dec 2018).

Comment: Anonymous posts gets removed after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

[Socrates](https://socrates.io) is run off firebase and running since 2012 it's almost as minimalist as it gets... it's beautiful and doesn't get in your way

Comment: Looks like the site is down

Answer (score 0):

[Markdown.press](https://markdown.press) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like the site is down now